How to properly debug routes
I'm having a bit of an issue learning Apache Camel.
I was trying to create a very simple rest service with jetty and Rest DSL, like so:
package org.examples.routes.camelRestRoute;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class CamelRestRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure()  {

        restConfiguration()
                .component("jetty")
                .host("localhost")
                .port(8091);

        rest("/api")
            .get("/hello")
            .to("direct:helloWorld");

        from("direct:helloWorld")
                .transform().simple("Hello, world");
    }
}

Unfortunately, it wasn't working. When I called curl on this endpoint, I got a HTTP 500 error, same thing from the browser. But the port was open while my program was running (checked with netstat). I have tracing enabled in apache camel, main.configure().setTracing(true); but even though more logs did show up this way, no errors were showing up in the log at all when I made a http request.
I've searched in a lot of places and couldn't find out what was wrong, examples directly from Apache Camel Documentation did not work either. Finally I've found an example on Stack Overflow which was working, commented out line by line to see what was necessary there that I didn't have, and it turned out that naming my direct route .routeId("Hello World!") was crucial. So now code looked like that:
package org.examples.routes.camelRestRoute;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class CamelRestRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure()  {

        restConfiguration()
                .component("jetty")
                .host("localhost")
                .port(8091);

        rest("/api")
            .get("/hello")
            .to("direct:helloWorld");

        from("direct:helloWorld")
                .routeId("helloWorld") // this is changed
                .transform().simple("Hello, wolrd");

    }


}

So my question basically is - how could I have know that? There is a paragraph about Inline Rest DSL as a single route but where is this information? Here?

To do this you MUST use direct endpoints, and each endpoint must be unique name per service.

Aren't the names generated automatically? Later on, in the description of parameters, this is written instead:

Inline routes in rest-dsl which are linked using direct endpoints. By default, each service in Rest DSL is an individual route, meaning that you would have at least two routes per service (rest-dsl, and the route linked from rest-dsl). Enabling this allows Camel to optimize and inline this as a single route. However, this requires using direct endpoints,** which must be unique per service**. This option is default false.

So not even names have to be unique, but routes, and mine were.
How do I debug stuff like that if it doesn't appear in logs? This is not the first time something doesn't work for me in camel and logs tell me nothing, so I want to know how to properly debug it.

Which java version are you using ?

Hi, I'm using Java 17
